# How to print a graph in graphviz with multiple properties displayed

Tags: c++, boost, graphviz, boost-graph

My question is based off of: [How to print a graph with a single property displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181183/how-to-print-a-boost-graph-in-graphviz-with-one-of-the-properties-displayed)

I am using bundled properties:

```
 typedef struct vert{
   std::string name;
 };

 typedef struct edge{
   int capacity;
   int weight;
 }; 

typedef adjacency_list<listS, vecS, undirectedS, vert, edge> Graph;
Graph g;
vector<int,int> ele;
```

I have the following called in a loop that *should* create the edges:

```
  edge prop;
  prop.weight = 5;
  prop.capacity = 4;
  add_edge(ele.first,ele.second, prop, g);
```

This segment is what prints the graph to dot format.

```
ofstream dot("graph.dot");
write_graphviz(dot, g, 
  boost::make_label_writer(boost::get(&vert::name, g)),
  boost::make_label_writer(boost::get(&edge::weight, g)),
  boost::make_label_writer(boost::get(&edge::capacity, g)));
```

The error is:

```
/usr/include/boost/graph/graphviz.hpp: In function ‘void boost::write_graphviz(std::ostream&, const Graph&, VertexPropertiesWriter, EdgePropertiesWriter, GraphPropertiesWriter, VertexID) [with Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, vert, edge, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, VertexPropertiesWriter = boost::label_writer<boost::bundle_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, vert, edge, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, long unsigned int, vert, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, EdgePropertiesWriter = boost::label_writer<boost::bundle_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, vert, edge, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int>, edge, int> >, GraphPropertiesWriter = boost::label_writer<boost::bundle_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, vert, edge, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int>, edge, int> >, VertexID = boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::property<boost::vertex_bundle_t, vert, boost::no_property>, long unsigned int>]’:
/usr/include/boost/graph/graphviz.hpp:260:   instantiated from ‘void boost::write_graphviz(std::ostream&, const Graph&, VertexPropertiesWriter, EdgePropertiesWriter, GraphPropertiesWriter) [with Graph = Graph, VertexPropertiesWriter = boost::label_writer<boost::bundle_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, vert, edge, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, long unsigned int, vert, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, EdgePropertiesWriter = boost::label_writer<boost::bundle_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, vert, edge, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int>, edge, int> >, GraphPropertiesWriter = boost::label_writer<boost::bundle_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, vert, edge, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int>, edge, int> >]’
file_format.cc:194:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/graph/graphviz.hpp:236: error: no match for call to ‘(boost::label_writer<boost::bundle_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, vert, edge, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int>, edge, int> >) (std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)’
```

It is strange to me because this works:

```
write_graphviz(dot, g,
  boost::make_label_writer(boost::get(&vert_info::name, g)));
```

and outputs the following:

```
graph G {
0[label="0"];
1[label="1"];
2[label="2"];
3[label="3"];
4[label="4"];
5[label="5"];
6[label="6"];
7[label="7"];
8[label="8"];
9[label=""];  // this is another problem that I will have to fix but beside the point
0--9 ;
0--5 ;
0--2 ;
0--1 ;
...
...
}
```

My goal is to have each node labeled, and each edge labelled with its capacity and weight.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can find [here](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/doc/write-graphviz.html) the list of all the overloads for `write_graphviz`. The reason for your first error is that the overload you tried to use expects a graph property writer in its fifth argument.

The helper function `make_label_writer` simply creates a property writer that assigns a single property from either a vertex or an edge of your graph to a graphviz vertex or edge attribute named `label`.

In order to achieve what you want you need to create a custom [`property writer`](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/doc/write-graphviz.html#concept%3aPropertyWriter) in which you assign each of your edge properties to the [graphviz attributes](http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs) you need. I would personally use `weight`->`label` and `capacity`->`taillabel` or `headlabel`.

```
template <class WeightMap,class CapacityMap>
class edge_writer {
public:
  edge_writer(WeightMap w, CapacityMap c) : wm(w),cm(c) {}
  template <class Edge>
  void operator()(ostream &out, const Edge& e) const {
    out << "[label=\"" << wm[e] << "\", taillabel=\"" << cm[e] << "\"]";
  }
private:
  WeightMap wm;
  CapacityMap cm;
};

template <class WeightMap, class CapacityMap>
inline edge_writer<WeightMap,CapacityMap> 
make_edge_writer(WeightMap w,CapacityMap c) {
  return edge_writer<WeightMap,CapacityMap>(w,c);
}
```

And finally your `write_graphviz` invocation would simply be:

```
ofstream dot("graph.dot");
write_graphviz(dot, g, 
  boost::make_label_writer(boost::get(&vert::name, g)),
  make_edge_writer(boost::get(&edge::weight,g),boost::get(&edge::capacity,g)));
```